# Can anyone find where this white space is coming from?

Tags: html, css, image, background, whitespace

I have some pretty basic html and css here, and for some reaseon my image that i have set with my css as the background image is not repeating vertically, or if it is it is covered by this white space, but the main problem her is that from the point where my image no longer repeats vertically there is pure white space, i have even tried setting the backgrond color of #content2 and the whitespace even over rides that. Can anyone see what im missing?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<div id="wrap">

<!--header starts-->
<div id="header">
<div id="name">
<h1>Comp <span>any</span> Name</h1>
</div><!--end name-->   
<div id="nav"><br>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="programs.html">Our Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ol>
</div><!--end nav-->
</div><!--end header-->
<!--header ends-->

<!--content1 starts-->
<div id="content1">
<img src="images/placeholder.png" width="400" height="323" alt="logo"> 
<div id="imgright">
<h2>What We Do</h2>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui o
    fficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<div id="button">
<h4>Request A Program</h4>
</div><!--end button-->
</div><!--end imgright-->
</div><!--end content1-->
<!--content1 ends-->

<!--content2 starts-->
<div id="content2">
<div id="one">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow1">
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p> 
</div><!--end one-->

<div id="two">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow2"> 
  <h3>About Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end two-->

<div id="three">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow3"> 
  <h3> View Our Programs</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end three-->  
</div><!--end content2-->
<!--content2 ends-->

<!--footer starts-->
<div id="footer">
<h5>Insert some footer information, copyright information also</h5>    
</div>    <!--end footer-->
<!--footer ends-->
</div><!--end wrap-->
</div><!--end body-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#body{
background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
margin-top:-25px;
padding:0;  
}
#wrap{
border-width:3px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:white;
width:1024px;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:5px;
}

#header h1{
font-size:36px;
font-family: Terminal, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: white;
}

span{
font-size:100px;
color:black;
font-family:brush script std, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#nav{
margin-top:-110px;
margin-bottom:75px;
margin-right:40px;
}

#nav ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#nav li {
display: block;
float: right;
}

#nav a {
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: white;
}

#nav a:hover { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: black;
}

#content1 img{
margin-left:25px;
}

#imgright{
margin-left:445px;
margin-top:-389px;
}

#button h4{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:24px;
color:white;
}

h2{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:48px;
}

#imgright p{
color: white;
font-size:24px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:20px;
}

#content2{
background-color:#2e3192;
}

#one, #two, #three{width:341.3px;}

#one h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}
#one p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#two h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}
#two p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#three h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;    
}

#three p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#one{
margin-top:50px;
}

#two{
margin-top:-104px;
margin-left:360px;
}

#three{
margin-top:-408px;
margin-left:720px;
}

#footer{

}
```

Comment: any picture that could help us to visualize your problem?

Comment: do you have a link to your website? I'm very lazy to see every lines of codes, just to see an error...

Comment: A JSFiddle reproducing this issue would be great

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle.net sample.

Comment: @YouMe you should go back and accept some of the answers as correct. No one will want to answer your questions in the future if you never accept answers.

Comment: @JohnSmith its been less than an hour, give me a minute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative margins throughout your CSS is the cause of this problem:

```
#two {
    margin-top: -104px;
    margin-left: 360px;
}
```

Instead of using large negative margins to move things, use floats: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp.

Here is a tutorial from CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/.

Anywhere you used negative margins, you need to replace with floats. The white-space is as expected, the negative margins you are setting aren't contributing to the height.

Comment: Generally speaking, beware of w3schools.  There's some bad info on the site.  It gets a bad wrap unnecessarily in some cases though.  Just be sure to double check the info that you get.

Comment: thats it thank you, i may not redo the floats but i will add positive padding on the other side in order to evn it out